# I encountered a challenging scenario while managing our GitHub repository's branches and merges

Tags: git, github

Initial Branch Setup: Our team originally had three branches named A, B, and C.

Deployment Branch Creation: To streamline deployment, we created a branch called 'abc', which was merged into the main branch.

Reversion of Deployment Merge: Later, we discovered an issue and decided to revert the 'abc' merge in the main branch. This action created another merge request, resulting in the reverted changes being merged into the main branch.

Individual Branch Merging: We then planned to merge each original branch (A, B, C) separately into the main branch.

Accidental Merge from Main to Branch B: However, during this process, there was an accidental merge of the main branch into branch B. This led to the unintended loss of changes in branch B due to the earlier reversion of the deployment merge.

Challenges Faced: Now, I'm facing two main challenges:

The changes in branch B have disappeared due to the accidental merge from the main branch.
Even if I revert to a commit prior to the accidental merge, merging branch B into the main branch will reintroduce the changes that were previously reverted, potentially causing conflicts with subsequent contributions to the main branch.
Seeking Guidance: I'm struggling to identify the correct approach to restore branch B to its previous state and integrate it into the main branch without causing conflicts with the reverted changes and subsequent contributions.

Any advice or insights on how to navigate this situation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Given that you have _merged_ `main` into `B`... assuming it's a real _merge_ and that it has been published, then it is not a good idea to just get the state of B branch back to what it was before the merge. Was `B` development a straight line since it separated from `main` up to the commit when you merged `main` into `B`? Were there commits of `B` already merged into `main`?

Comment: Oh... I just found the answer myself: of course there has been merges of `B`  into `main`. That's why they were reverted in the first place. Ok... so, if `B`  is a straight line up to the point where you merged `main` into `B` it should be enough to rewrite the commits that had already been merged from `B` into `main` on a separate branch and then rebase those commits on top of `B`.... then you should get all the work of `B` back in there. Let me create an answer with charts.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.... so, suppose you start from here:

```
* ooo merge of main into B (B)
|\ 
* | nnn 6th commit in B # not merged in main yet
* | mmm 5th commit in B # not merged in main yet
* | lll 4th commit in B # not merged in main yet
| * kkk something in main (main)
| * jjj Reversal of commits of B up to this point
| * iii some commit in main
| * hhh merge of commits in B into main
|/|
* | ggg 3rd commit in B
* | fff 2nd commit in B
* | eee 1st commit in B
|/
* ddd commit from main before we started to work in B
* ccc
* bbb
* aaa
```

If this is kind of what you have *and* you dod not anything fancy, then what you *lost* from `B`  are the changes from the commits that had been merged into `main`. Any commits that you had performed into `B` past the last commit from `B` that was merged into `main`  is still in `B`.

If that is the case, then I *think* that git won't complain if you try to cherry-pick commits in `ddd..ggg` (`ddd` is the commit from `main` before you started working on `B` proper, `ggg` is the last commit from `B` that has been merged already into `main`.... so:

```
git checkout B
git cherry-pick ddd..ggg
```

Then you should have:

```
* ggg' 3rd commit in B (B)
* fff' 2nd commit in B
* eee' 1st commit in B
* ooo merge of main into B
|\ 
* | nnn 6th commit in B
* | mmm 5th commit in B
* | lll 4th commit in B
| * kkk something in main (main)
| * jjj Reversal of commits of B up to this point
| * iii some commit in main
| * hhh merge of commits in B into main
|/|
* | ggg 3rd commit in B
* | fff 2nd commit in B
* | eee 1st commit in B
|/
* ddd commit from main before we started to work in B
* ccc
* bbb
* aaa
```

I don't think that git gill complain about the cherry-pick because the commits are already part of the history of your branch... *however*, if that is the case, git can be tricked by rewriting those commits like this:

```
git checkout -b temp ddd
git cherry-pick HEAD..ggg # reapply those 3 commits, new commits will be created
git rebase B
```

If you like the result:

```
git checkout B
git merge temp # you should see a fast-forward over here
```